# WSO2 5.3.0 IWA - not working with Java 1.8 or later version

Tags: java, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to enable IWA authentication with java 1.7 its working fine but with the later version, it's giving NTLM token not found error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

EOL for IS 5.3.0 was back in Jan 2020. The current versions support 1.8 and still have IWA as a [feature](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.12.0/learn/configuring-iwa-single-sign-on/). My recommendation would be tup upgrade to at least 5.10.0